# How to get file path for pdf in android Marshmallow

Tags: java, android

I tried to get path from

```
 Intent intent = new Intent();             
            intent.setType("application/pdf");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(
                    Intent.createChooser(intent, "Complete action using"), 2);
```

But I did't get path from `Marshamallow`, I can get path from lollipop.

How I can get file path from internal storage?

Comment: what do you need this path for?

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to use file provider for that.
Refer this.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider

Answer (score 0):

When you start an activity using `startActivityForResult`, the calling activity will get the results (if any) in `onActivityResult`. You should override that method in your calling activity...

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {

}
```

This will method will get called as soon as the results are returned from the activity started by `startActivityForResult`. You can use the `requestCode` parameter to match (or filter out) the results you are expecting. In your case, you should check that `requestCode` is equal to 2 which is the value you provided in `startActivityForResult`.

If the `requestCode` is equal to 2, then you know that you need to process a PDF file. The intent parameter "could" have the path of that PDF file...

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    if(requestCode == 2 && data != null){
        //This is the uri to the file (which could be null)
        Uri uri = data.getData();

        if(uri != null){
            Log.i("LOG_TAG", String.format("uri path = %s", uri));
        }
    }

}
```

Now, to browse and select files you will do it the following way (Android Kitkat and above...I think)...

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
intent.setType("application/pdf");

startActivityForResult(intent, SELECT_FILE_REQUEST_CODE);
```

Then you receive the selected PDF uri as mentioned above

Comment: what about absolute file path?